# Using Linq to find a value in comma separated value in a List

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a File Class and each file has List of Rows. Each row has Code which has comma seperated values. I need to find if a particular value exists in the comma seperated data.

```
public class File
{
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public string Code{ get; set; }
}
```

Here code has comma sperated values like abc, def, ghi || xyz, ghj, klm

I need to pick the Row which has abc as code out of the list of rows i have in the file using Linq

Comment: Use `string.Split` then the LINQ `Any` extension method against the resulting array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a boolean:

```
var isPresent = listOfRows.Any(r => r.Code.Split(",").Any(s => (---your condition---)));
```

If you want rows with Code property value matching your condition:

```
var rows = listOfRows.Where(r => r.Code.Split(",").Any(s => (---your condition---)));
```

If you only want Code property values:

```
var values = listOfRows.Select(r => r.Code.Split(",")).Where(s => (---your condition---));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
foreach (var line in filelines) {
  var exists = line.Split(',').Any(s => s == mySearchValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Split` and `Enumerable.Any`:

```
string value = "search_me";
bool hasValue = file.Rows.Any(fr => fr.Code.Split(',').Any(v => v == value));
```

or `Contains`:

```
file.Rows.Any(fr => fr.Code.Split(',').Contains(value));
```

**Update** (acc. your edit): if you want to get the first `Row` which contains this code:

```
Row row = file.Rows.FirstOrDefault(fr => fr.Code.Split(',').Contains(value));
if(row != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

or all rows:

```
IEnumerable<Row> allRows = file.Where(fr => fr.Code.Split(',').Contains(value));
foreach(Row row in allRows)
{
    // ...
}
```